# CrmServiceClient - Performance Issues

Tags: performance, oauth-2.0, dynamics-crm-365

We are using CrmServiceClient as a singleton instance for all the methods being used. Other configurations are

RequireNewInstance = True;
AuthType = OAuth

Normally it works as expected but in load testing, it is getting stuck at Monitor.Enter() of RetrieveMutliple()

Dynatrace logs show, it is taking 99.9% of the time there only and this is how it is breaching the SLA. In the On-Prem setup, it was working fine (AuthType was IFD for On-Prem).

Is there any specific setting we need to do for D365?

Comment: did you manage to find a solution for this? we are using RequireNewInstance = false but still get performance issue. Did you find  anything useful to make the performance better?

Answer (score 1):

`RequireNewInstance` should be set to `False`, unless you have a specific reason to set it otherwise, e.g. you are using a single `CrmServiceClient` instance to access multiple endpoints.

The lock on `Monitor.Enter()` indicates multiple threads are getting queued waiting for a free connection object. You could speed up your application by introducing a pool of `CrmServiceClient` objects. This should work in a way similar to ADO.NET connection pooling. Remember a `CrmServiceClient` object can only handle one HTTP request at a time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use RequireNewInstance=True and to have multiple 'threads' or instances of CrmServiceClient to connect.

1. Use DisableCrossThreadSafeties = true - that will ensure CrmServiceClient isn't trying to only use a single connection back to Dataverse - this also means you need to handle your own thread safety with CrmServiceClient.
2. instantiate a singleton CrmServiceClient (ie: _CrmService) to create a single connection to use at startup or on the first operation. Then, for every execution, make sure to call CrmServiceClient.Clone() to get a unique instance:

```
using(var service=_CrmService.Clone()){ 
    service.Execute(OrganizationRequest); 
}
```

This approach will give each operation it's own instance/connection back to the service, the Using will ensure disposal of each of those connections/clients.